# how to add infiniteProgress to a webbrowser

Tags: java, codenameone

I have 2 questions:

1. what the difference between `webBrowser` and `BrowserComponent`?
2. Is there any way I can add an `infiniteProgress` to `webbrowser`, the `infiniteProgress` will automatically dispose only when the webbrowser is fully loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like

```
InfiniteProgress prog = new InfiniteProgress();
final Dialog dlg = prog.showInifiniteBlocking();
final WebBrowser wb = findLoginWebBrowser();
((BrowserComponent) wb.getInternal()).setBrowserNavigationCallback(
    new BrowserNavigationCallback() {
        public boolean shouldNavigate(String url) {
            //your condition
            if(xyz){
                Display.getInstance().callSerially(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        //do whatever you wants
                        dlg.dispose();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
);
```

but this one will work when you are know what URL you are passing/processing.

`WebBrowser` is a more general specialization of `BrowserComponent`. Old devices didn't support the `BrowserComponent` API and the `WebBrowser` is smart enough to detect that and fallback to the old `HTMLComponent` API.

If you are only targeting modern smartphones and aren't targeting RIM devices use the `BrowserComponent` directly.

Comment: Edited the answer to include an answer to the second question